# Как найти угол между двумя векторами?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вектор

Есть окружность r=44 на ней лежат точки: (0; 44) (28;33) и др.
Как найти между ними угол?
[Есть сайт](https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/angl/) на нем можно вписать начало и конец вектора и получить угол. Но если я вписываю туда значения по кордам меньше нуля то угол как бы начинает отсчитыватся с другого места. если я считаю угол для точек 0; 44 и 28; 33 то угол ~40 а если для 0; 44 и 33; -26 то угол 51 тоесть этого впринципе не может быть. Мне нужно понять как универсально посчитать угол в любом из 4 половинок координат. Самое важное что потом по формулам надо будет перенести в программу. По этому и нужно понять почему так происходит. Если написать на сайте точки 0; 44 и 0; -44 показывает расчет по формулам 0 а по логике должно 180.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Формула скалярного произведения через косинус к вашим услугам...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К каждому вектору `(x, y)` примените `atan2(y, x)` ([atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)) - получится угол между данным вектором и осью `X`. Углы будут в диапазоне `(-pi, pi]`. Переведите углы в градусы, если нужно. Вычтите углы, приведите разницу в нужный диапазон.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! =)